# Is {{outlet}} mandatory to use in Application template?

Tags: ember.js

Without {{outlet}} helper, my template is being rendered through application template.

Is this feasible as I have read that template would be rendered through {{outlet}}.

Comment: Can you please explain the situation a bit more? Are you saying that the application.hbs file is being rendered and does not contain an outlet? Or that other templates are being rendered despite there being no `{{outlet}}` in application.hbs?

Answer (score 3):

An outlet is required for any child route to be rendered into its parent. If your application route's template doesn't have an outlet, no child route will be rendered. However, if you don't have an application template defined, the child route will be rendered as if you wrote a template containing only `{{outlet}}`.

[Check out this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6cceef90046a2fce7c8c790b1e71ab94) where `application.hbs`'s outlet has been commented out. With no outlet, the content of `application.hbs` still rendered (including the component and partial), but `route.hbs` is not rendered. If you remove line 2 of `application.hbs` to uncomment the outlet you'll see the contents of `route.hbs` rendered into the outlet of `application.hbs`. Now, if you delete `application.hbs` using the File menu, only `route.hbs`'s content will be rendered.